# Write into Word file slows down at page two

Tags: c#, office-interop

there are products to be written into a table in a Word file.
The template contains the table of contents and the template table on page 1.
Writing to the table on the first page is relatively fast, but starting on the second page, it takes almost twice as long to write per cell.
Is there any way to speed this up?

```
using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
public static void CreateWordDocument(Catalogue pCatalogue, Word._Document oWDFile, string pPicturePath, string pStorePath, Word.Application oWD) {
        var wordSelection = oWD.Selection;
        var oMissing = (object)Missing.Value;
        var wordTableCount = oWDFile.Tables.Count;

        if (wordTableCount > 0) {

            var tableToUse = oWDFile.Tables[wordTableCount];
            var range = tableToUse.Range;
            range.Copy();

            foreach (var currentChapter in pCatalogue.ChapterList) {
//Do Stuff

                var groupCounter = 1;
                var articleCounter = 0;

                foreach (var currentGroup in currentChapter.ArticleList) {
                    //Get the current row depending on the current articlegroup and existing tables
                    tableToUse.Cell(HelpCollection.GetWordTableRow(groupCounter, true, wordTableCount), 2).Range.Text = currentGroup[0].ID;
//Do Stuff

                    if (groupCounter > 5) {
                        wordSelection.EndKey(Word.WdUnits.wdStory, Word.WdMovementType.wdMove);
                        Word.Table tableCopy = oWDFile.Tables.Add(wordSelection.Range, 1, 1, ref oMissing, oMissing);
                        tableCopy.Range.Paste();
                        articleCounter = 0;
                        groupCounter = 1;
                        wordTableCount = oWDFile.Tables.Count;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        try {
            oWDFile.SaveAs2(pStorePath + @"\" + pCatalogue.CatalogueName + ".docx", oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            //Message
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of appending the table directly, I created a new paragraph. This seems to make a big difference, because it fixed the problem.

```
wordSelection.EndKey(Word.WdUnits.wdStory, Word.WdMovementType.wdMove);
object breakType = Word.WdBreakType.wdPageBreak;
Word.Selection.InsertBreak(ref breakType);
Word.Paragraph tableCopy = oWDFile.Paragraphs.Add(oWD.Selection.Range);
tableCopy.Range.Paste();
```